# Does Word provide an explicit menu option to check in/out of SharePoint?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, sharepoint

We use on-premises SharePoint and often when opening a Word file, it prompts me with a yellow header bar to make a document editable, and check it out. Some times when saving, I am similarly prompted to check it in to SharePoint from Word, without having to go back to Sharepoint.
[image]
[image]

But other times, I don't get these prompts and have to go back to the SharePoint web interface and manually do it.
Does Word provide a way to check a document in/out from the menus somewhere in the event these prompts are not shown?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1556142/8672) help, if you prefer opening in View mode?

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-click a button at top, **Customize the Ribbon**
   [image]
2. At the top of the left column choose **All Commands**, scroll down then click **'Check In'**, on bottom of right column click **New Group**, then click **Add** in middle, click **'Check Out'**, click **Add**, click **OK**. This seems to be what you need from what I can tell.
   [image]